# MDX Variance Parallel period

Tags: mdx, variance

Please could you assist.

I have the following dimensions:

Dim Period End: Contains Months and weeks. Note the weeks can fall into multiple months. For example in Dec you may forecast for a week in Jan. In Jan you may forecast for the same week as well. 
Dim Forecast Period: Contains the period that the week actually belongs to. For example, if you forecast for 28/01/2018 this falls into Jan 2018 
Dim Forecast Description: Descriptions such as Actual or forecast concatenated by the week number 
Dim Contract: Contracts

1 Measure:

Inflow

I am trying to calculate the variance but are not getting the correct results using:

([Period End].[Week Commencing Date].CurrentMember.prevmember, [Measures].[Inflow])

for each period end and week I want to see what the previous forecasted value is so I can then calculate a variance.

I want to take a sum of what they forecasted in Dec 2017 for forecast period Jan 2018 and compare this to what actually happened in Jan 2018. I use one Inflow measure which has actuals and forecasted values.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the script in which that measure is not working